# Wifi stopped working, "Unknown symbol wireless_nlevent_flush"

Tags: wifi, kernel-modules, dmesg

As of this afternoon the wifi on my Dell XPS 13 stopped working (running Debian sid with kernel 4.4.0-1-amd64). `lspci` detects my wifi card, but `ifconfig -a` shows only the loopback interface.

I tried plugging in a USB wifi dongle which I have used recently with this laptop, and this also does not get recognized as a network interface. Both during startup and immediately after plugging in a USB wifi dongle, the following message appears in `dmesg`:

```
cfg80211: Unknown symbol wireless_nlevent_flush (err 0)
```

`cfg80211` sounds like it would be used for configuring 802.11 (i.e. wifi) so I suspect this kernel module isn't getting loaded correctly. Indeed, if I try to `modprobe cfg80211` I receive the following error:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'cfg80211':? Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
```

and checking `dmesg` I see the same message as above.

Googling for `"unknown symbol wireless_nlevent_flush"` yields zero results, although googling for just `wireless_nlevent_flush` seems to imply that it relates to `wext` somehow. [One page](https://dev.openwrt.org/ticket/8237) suggested that `rfkill` must be loaded before `cfg80211`, but `rfkill` is already loaded. I would be very grateful for any advice.

Comment: This looks like a software error, more precisely like a module that doesn't match the kernel version. What have you upgraded recently?

Comment: checking my apt logs, I ran updates a couple days before this issue manifested (and it's entirely possible that there was no reboot in between). The kernel, linux-image-4.4.0-1-amd, updated from version 4.4.2-3 to 4.4.6-1. Checking the deb cache, it looks like the 4.4.2-3 deb is still there, I'll try downgrading and crossing my fingers!

Comment: Hooray! Did a `dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-1-amd64_4.4.2-3_amd64.deb` and now I can internet again. If you would please write your comment as an answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `cfg80211` module and your running kernel are incompatible. The internal programming interfaces in the kernel change rather frequently, so when you upgrade your kernel, you need to keep modules in synch. (The exception is a few out-of-tree modules that are specifically maintained to work across a large range of kernel versions.)

If you upgraded your kernel package since the last reboot, you probably have a running kernel that no longer matches the kernel version(s) on disk, and so `modprobe` is trying to load a module for a more recent kernel. Make sure not to uninstall a `linux-image-…` package corresponding to the running kernel. You can check the running kernel version with the command `uname -r`; with Debian's package naming convention, the package `linux-image-$(uname -r)` should be installed.

If you've removed the package, then you'll either need to reinstall it or reboot. To reinstall, check if you still have the package in `/var/cache/apt/archives`. If you don't, look for the package on [snapshot.debian.org](http://snapshot.debian.org/package/linux/) (with a version matching the *version* of the `linux-image-…` package, i.e. the second column of `dpkg -l`, which is not always exactly the version contained in the name).